# Change Account login text to icon, standard magento or any other

Tags: magento-2.1, link

Where do I start if I want to update the text of login on the frontend to a icon?
I have installed grunt, downloaded the css libraries and icon sets but Im stuck. A hint?

I also wonder how I can convert the login text link to a custom button..

Comment: Were you able to achieve the result you were looking for? I'm having the same question.

Answer (score 5):

To change login text link You can start with template `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml`. Add new method to verify if user is login/logout and add `class` and `text` whatever you want.

```
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>">
    <a <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLinkAttributes(); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $dataPostParam; ?>>
        <span class="<?php echo $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('class-log-in') : __('class-log-out'); ?>">
            <?php echo $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out Custom Text') : __('Sign In Custom Text'); ?>
        <span/>
    <a/>
</li>
```

Then You can customize your `<span class="class-log-in">` or `<span class="class-log-out">` in *.less file with mixin:

```
.lib-icon-font(@your-icon-name);
```