# How to change text "sign in" to "Login" in top header

Tags: magento2, login, text

I want to rename text "**Sign in**" to "**Login**" in my header top.

Please refer attached file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override this Block in your custom module with **getLabel()** function.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/AuthorizationLink.php

here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/AuthorizationLink.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Account;

class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Logout') : __('Login'); // Custom Labels
        // return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In'); // Default Magento labels
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution works for you ?

Comment: This is a better solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191695/change-account-login-text-to-icon-standard-magento-or-any-other

Answer (score 0):

> app\code\Vender\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vender_Module::authorization.phtml</argument>
                </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vender\Module\view\frontend\templates\authorization.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink */
$dataPostParam = '';
$customClass = "demo-login";
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
    $customClass = "logoutajax";
}
?>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>">
    <a <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLinkAttributes(); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $dataPostParam; ?> class="<?php echo $customClass ?>">
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel());
        ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

**I hope this will help you!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the translation csv? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Comment: I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple way is to add default text with your text into** `app/design/frontend/Custom/default/i18n/en_US.csv`

**like**

```
"Sign In","Login"
```

clear cache after that

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i tried above method, but still showing "Sign In" in top header

Comment: try to static content deploy(s:s:d) command

Comment: i tried. but doesn't change any thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Translate Inline tool:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/translate-inline.html?_ga=2.115589253.2067100504.1650141776-284093093.1649853465