# How to replace the Sign in and Sign out with an icon?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to replace the "Sign in" Link in `header.links` with an icon. Search stack exchange I was only able to add

```
 <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">account-link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

this to `default.xml`

That's all nice and good but it only adds a new link "My Account" which I could replace with an icon with CSS. I can also hide the "Sign in" with CSS but if signed in, then there is no Sign Out since the "My Account" link will only forward to the account.

In short: How to replace the Sign in and Sign out with an icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer
[Change Account login text to icon, standard magento or any other](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191695/change-account-login-text-to-icon-standard-magento-or-any-other)
Good luck!!